# Laravel 5: Redirecting to external link on POST request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The function below is called through a POST request. I need to retrieve URL from my database and open the link in a new tab. I'm using the `Redirect::away()` function for this. But it gives a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I have tried calling this function in a GET request and it works perfectly fine.

```
public function generateURL(Request $request) {

    $screenRow = \App\ScreenshotRow::find($request->input('row_ID'));
    $baseURL = $screenRow->BaseURL;

    $screenshot = \App\Screenshot::where('Setname', '=', $screenRow->Setname)->get();
    $pageURL = $screenshot[0]['PageURL'];

    if ($baseURL == "") {
        return Redirect::away($PageURL);
    }

    else
        return Redirect::away($baseURL);
}
```

Is there any way to calling this function in response to a POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use an Ajax Form and redirect the User with Javascript.

Make sure to give your Form an `ID`

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('your.route') }}">
...
...
<button type="submit">Submit the Form</button>
```

And make this Form working with Ajax

```
<script>
    $('#myForm [type="submit]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = jQuery(this).parents("form:first");
        var dataString = form.serialize();
        var formAction = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : formAction,
            data : dataString,
            success : function(data){
                var url = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                console.log(data); 
                // Redirect to a new tab with the given url
                window.open(url.success, '_blank');
            },
            error : function(data){
                var error = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                console.log(error);
                // Do what ever you want with an Error Message
                alert(error)
            }
        },"json");
    });
</script>
```

Okay - So if the Form receives a success Message, the `success` function is executed, otherwise the `error` function.

Lets go to the Backend Controller which handles the Request

```
public function generateURL(Request $request) {

    $screenRow = \App\ScreenshotRow::find($request->input('row_ID'));
    $baseURL = $screenRow->BaseURL;

    $screenshot = \App\Screenshot::where('Setname', '=', $screenRow->Setname)->get();
    $pageURL = $screenshot[0]['PageURL'];

    // Return a JSON Success Message with a Success HTTP Status Code
    if ($baseURL == "") {
        return response()->json(['success' => $PageURL], 200);
    }

    // Return a JSON Error Message with a Error HTTP Status Code
    else
        return response()->json(['error' => $baseURL], 400);
}
```

Now if your Backend throws a Success Message the success function of the Ajax Form is called which redirects to a new tab based on the given url which you passed in your Backend Controller Success Response.

**NOTE**

To avoid the `tokenmismatchexception` on an Ajax Request, you should add the `csrf_token` to your `meta` Section in your `<head>`.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And fetch this `csrf_token` on every Form Request

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: It still gives the MethodNotAllowedHttpException. I have also tried this on a GET request and it gives no problem there.

Comment: I would simply use an Ajax Form and redirect the user with window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: But how do I catch the JSON response that I return with Response::json() in my html code?